# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str using Python Core API?

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to filter some data using the Python Core API, which is through Apache Spark, but I am coming into this error, and I am unable to solve it in terms of the data I have:

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Now, this is a sample of my data structure:

This is the code I am using to filter my data, but it keeps giving me that error. I am simply trying to return the business_id, city and stars from my dataset.

```
(my_rdd
    .filter(lambda x: x['city']=='Toronto')
    .map(lambda x: (x['business_id'], x['city'], x['stars']))
).take(5)
```

Any guidance on how to filter my data would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: The example you gave, is it one item of `my_rdd`, or `my_rdd` entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sinc your data is nested in tuples, you need to specify the tuple indices in your `filter` and `map`:

```
result = (my_rdd
    .filter(lambda x: x[1][1]['city']=='Toronto')
    .map(lambda x: (x[1][1]['business_id'], x[1][1]['city'], x[1][1]['stars']))
)

print(result.collect())
[('7v91woy8IpLrqXsRvxj_vw', 'Toronto', 3.0)]
```

Comment: If you're talking about `result` RDD then you can try `result.sort(lambda r: r[2])`

Comment: That's because your dictionary is nested within two tuples, so you need to specify the tuple indices in order to access the dictionary.

Comment: x[1][0][0]['name'] or x[1][1]['name']

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaking in the use of `filter` and `map` here. Both of them are used to update lists, and returns lists.

Both of them take a function as parameter (that's the case in the object version, you can also find a functional version which takes the input list as second parameter) and apply it on each item of the input list to build the output list. What differs though is their usage of the function:

- `filter` uses it to, well, filter the input list. The function should return a boolean which indicates whether or not to include the item in the output list.
- `map` uses it to build a new list of the same length as the old one, but with values updated using the provided function.

Now that being said, I believe you have the error `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str` when you try to filter the list.

On the first loop, the `filter` function will try to run the function against the first element of the list. This first element is the tuple `('7v91woy8IpLrqXsRvxj_vw', (({'average_stars': 3.41, 'compliment_cool': 9, ...})))`. The problem is that you are trying to access a value of this tuple using a string, as if it was a dictionary, which is not permitted in python (and doesn't make much sense).

To extract the data you need, I would go with something much more simple:

```py
item = my_rdd[0]
(item[1][1]['business_id'], item[1][1]['city'], item[1][1]['stars'])
```

Comment: Perhaps the OP hasn't made it clear, but my_rdd is a Spark RDD, not a Python list. You can't do `my_rdd[0]` - RDDs don't work that way.

Comment: @mck oh. Yeah I didn't figured this out. Guess the `filter` and `map` make more sense then.

Comment: Sorry, it is Spark - my sincere apologies.